# Preg_match Date / with or without leading 0

Tags: php, regex

when i want to convert a date so that i can "feed" it to MySQL (mm/dd/yyyy -> yyyy-mm-dd) this preg_match works fine

```
$new_date = preg_replace("!([01][0-9])/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})!", "$3-$1-$2", $data[$c]);
```

with dates like

```
04/02/2012, 12/31/2012
```

but it fails when i get input like

```
12/1/2011, 1/4/2011
```

how to fix it due to i'm total noob to regex... :(

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
!(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})!
```

`\d` means a digit, and I think it's handier than `[0-9]`, and they are almost equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
!([01]?[0-9])/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{4})!
```

The `{1,2}` on the second group means 1 or 2 digits between 0-9.  I also made the first part accept 1 or 2 digits so you can match 3/12/2012 and 03/12/2012.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :D i think i should rly take some lessons in regex due to i think i will need them more often in future to validate user input

Comment: Check out www.regular-expressions.info which is a great site for learning.  Here is the [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php) reference from php.net which goes into some basics about regex, modifiers, and patterns as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier just to work with dates then use regexes. The [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object makes this easy:

```
$date = new DateTime('1/1/2013');
$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // Outputs 2013-01-01
```

Comment: how it will know which is mm or dd 1st or 2nd?

Comment: I think he means in the constructor.

Comment: kk thanks... but in this case cause in the script is already the regex so i can simply exchange the pattern without changing smth else

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($input));
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) works with almost any format.